# Java: Scanner class

Tags: java

I'd like to ask something about Scanner class that I don't seem to quite get.

If we use Scanner methods, for example hasNextInt(), why do we check for this before even making it take the input? Here's an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ScannerClass{
      public static void main(String[] args){

           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("Type a string: ");
           if(scan.hasNextInt())
                System.out.println("A string is required");
           String string = scan.nextLine();
      }
}
```

How does this work?

Comment: What does the [javadoc for `hasNextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) say?

Comment: It's not reasonable that people might down vote this user's question... There are a lot of questions on the Scanner class. Why not simply help the user out? Not everyone is an expert.

Comment: @AlvinBunk A downvote indicates: "This question does not show any **research effort**; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: Hi @tnw. Understood, but I've seen a lot of questions here on stackoverflow regarding the Scanner class, and I don't think this one deserves a down vote. Plus, it makes the poster think they've done something wrong, and you haven't explained in comment on how they can edit the post to improve the response....

Comment: @AlvinBunk Feel free to head over to meta to beat the dead horse regarding comments and downvotes.

Comment: I upvoted you @tnw for that comment ;-) Good point.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code that you provided you are checking "hasNextInt()" but in your prompt you asked for a "String". Instead you would want to check for a "hasNextLine()", which verifies a carriage return was entered.

There is no "hasNextString()" method, but you can use "hasNext(String pattern)" to check for a particular pattern.

I suggestion reading the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) more and get familiar with them. I don't know if you are using Java 1.8, but those dos are the latest. Hope this helps you. If not, ask more questions.